# JavaScript write function - stop displaying html in browser

Tags: javascript

I have the following JavaScript, which correctly writes out a file for the html I have. But, it also displays this html as a table in the browser. Can I prevent this from being displayed, but still get the file?

```
        var strExcelHtml = < .... some valid html .... >
        var oWin = window.open("about:blank", "_blank");
        oWin.document.write(strExcelHtml);
        oWin.document.close();
        var success = oWin.document.execCommand('SaveAs', false, fileName)
        oWin.close();
```

Comment: Probably just remove `oWin.document.write(strExcelHtml);`

Comment: Add some CSS to make the `<body>` of the document hidden?

Comment: My html is a table. What if I style it thusly: "<table style='display:none;'> etc etc; - Anything wrong with doing this?